# Is it possible to alter function's body with macro?

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

Is it possible (and how) to get the function's body with macro.

For instance, suppose I have a function defined as

```
function foo (h::AbstractArray)
    1. / (0.5 * h[i - 1, j, k] + h[i, j, k + 1])
end
```

I would like to write a macro `@permute_indices` that would alter the function body in a way, that all the array index accessors get permuted like this:

```
julia> @macroexpand :(@permute_indices(foo, Dict(1=>2, 2=>3, 3=>1)))
  1. / (0.5 * h[i, j - 1, k] + h[i + 1, j, k])
```

Comment: I am not sure you can do this as `foo` can have many methods so `@permute_indices` would not know which `foo` to work on. But I guess you could write a macro `@permute_indices` that is put before `foo` definition that defines several methods for this function i.e. takes the expression defining a method and spits out several method definitions (the original and the one with permuted indices - in general even more than one).

Comment: Additionally you might want investigating https://github.com/jrevels/Cassette.jl maybe this is what would suit your needs?